# How can I pull back float data, not color, generated in a shader to the CPU?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, sfml

I wrote a shader that generates noise, it uses gl_TexCoord[0].xy (a thing generated by SFML) as input and outputs a float for every pixel.

I want the data on the CPU, as an array of 32bits float.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
//using opengl 3.0 (I also tried 3.2)
ContextSettings settings(0, 0, 0, 3, 0);
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowsize.x, windowsize.y),
    "yada", 7, settings
);
```

Here I overwrite the texture after the texture is created. I'm using windows which only has opengl1.1 headers, so I have to manually set GL_R32F (found in glad done by dav1d):

```
#ifndef GL_R32F 
#define GL_R32F 0x822E // found this in glad.h for opengl 3.0, easy guess is that this value doesn't change across opengl versions
#endif
auto handle = sprite_perlin.getTexture()->getNativeHandle(); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);
auto size = sprite_perlin.getTexture()->getSize();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
        }
```

Here I read the texture data into values:

```
float values[4096];
// whole_size is the size of the texture, here it is 60
if(whole_size*whole_size < 4096)
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, values);

Image brought_back;
brought_back.create(whole_size, whole_size, Color::Red);

float mi = 1e20, ma = -1e20;

for (int i = 0; i < whole_size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < whole_size; ++j) {
        brought_back.setPixel(i, j, { 0,Uint8(255.f*values[whole_size*i + j]),0 });
        ma = max(values[whole_size*i + j], ma);
        mi = min(values[whole_size*i + j], mi);
    }
}
```

mi and ma are both to 0.0f;

Here is the noise generated when showed on a sprite with the shader (with some color function that takes a float) The shader works as intended, I would just like to retrieve the data as float on the CPU.

[image: noise example]

Here is a simplified version of the shader:

```
uniform int texture_size;

float get_value_at(ivec2 pixel_coord) {
    //dummy value
    return 0.34f;
}

void main(){
    ivec2 pix_pos = ivec2(gl_TexCoord[0].xy*texture_size);

    float val = get_value_at(pix_pos);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(val,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: You should definitely not define your own OpenGL constants. Use something like glad, glew, or any other extension loading mechanism you like.

Comment: it works, constants are the same across opengl versions. SFML is already using GLAD

Comment: About the real problem: Could it be that you are misunderstanding what texture are doing? There is a missing part where you somewhere move/copy the rendered data to the texture. Otherwise it will never contain any values that you render. Either you attach the texture to a framebuffer or you read the default renderbuffer back directly. You might want to look into [Render to Texture](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) if you really need it in a texture, but I suggest reading the backbuffer directly using glReadPixels.

Comment: SFML actually provides the [RenderTexture](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php) class to facilitate rendering to a texture. And it has a method to copy the GPU texture back to an image in memory too: `sf::Image img = renderTexture.getTexture().copyToImage();` You may even be able to generate the image asynchronously with a separate OpenGL context if you want to go that far.

Comment: @Romen that's not what I want to do. I want to get an array of float. A texture is made of 4 8bits channels colors.

Comment: @Jokoon, sorry I wasn't aware until looking closer that SFML did not support floating point textures. You can still do the same thing as that SFML line with pure OpenGL but using `GL_FLOAT` for a floating-point render target. See the 'Render to Texture' link in BDL's comment above.

Comment: have you read my code? `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);` declares the texture as float. what do you mean by a "floating-point render target"?

Comment: @jokoon, I have read your code. You can render your shader to a texture by following this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/). The texture that you bind as the render target (aka frame buffer) should be set up as `GL_FLOAT`, then you can download that texture with `glGetTexImage` into an array of float values on the CPU. It looks like you've written the code for most of this already, but you seem to have missed the step where you bind a custom framebuffer.

Comment: @Romen https://bpaste.net/show/fUx1

Comment: (sorry, before your last answer, I noticed you already posted that tutorial and I hadn't checked it)

Comment: @jokoon, After reading that tutorial, let me know if you still need guidance. You need to bind a custom frame buffer, render with your shader and `sprite_perlin` texture to that framebuffer, then copy the texture bound to that frame buffer back to your `values` array with `glGetTexImage`.

Comment: @Romen After reading SFML code for RenderTextureFBO.cpp (github) and reading the tutorial, I can't manage to intersect what part of the code I can use. IRC people suggested me to use SFML to do what I want... here is some changes I made https://bpaste.net/show/237d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pull back float data, [...]

The output of the fragment shader is written to the framebuffer. The precision depends on the format of the framebuffer. The format of the [Default Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) is (probably) 1 byte for each color channel. So it doesn't matter which type you use when you read the color from the buffer. The precision is lost when the color is written into the buffer.

If you want to store the colors with a higher precision, then you've to render to a [Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), that uses a [Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) or [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) with a format that can store the values with an higher precision.
See [Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format).

If you want to render to a framebuffer, then I recommend to read a tutorial like [Framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers) or [Render To Texture](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) respectively [Khronos wiki - Framebuffer Object Extension Examples](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Extension_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_buffer_.28p-buffer_replacement.29).

Anyway, I'll provide an example. You've to setup a framebuffer with provides the internal format `GL_R32F` (or `GL_RGBA32F` for 4 color channels).

Either setup a render buffer with the internal format `GL_R32F` and attach it to the framebuffer:

```cpp
// render buffer with internal format `GL_RGBA32F`
GLuint rbo32F = 0;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo32F);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo32F);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_R32F, size.x, size.y);

// framebuffer with attached render buffer
GLuint fbo = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo32F);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Or setup a texture with the format `GL_R32F` and attach it to the framebuffer. If you just to want to create a texture, which is used for further rendering, then is is the approach for you used to be. There is no need to upload the image to the CPU, because the image is already rendered to a texture, which can be used further.

```cpp
// texture with internal format `GL_R32F`
GLuint tex32F = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &tex32F);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex32F);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// framebuffer with attached texture
GLuint fbo = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex32F, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

In both cases you should validate the completeness of the frambuffer `glCheckFramebufferStatus`:

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    // error handling
    // [...]
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Bind the framebuffer before rendering:

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
```

After you've draw the geometry, the texture can be read by [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml). e.g.:

```cpp
std::vector<GLfloat> buffer(size.x * size.y * 1); // widht * height * 1 color channel
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex32F);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, buffer.data());
```

Comment: Wouldn't GL_R32F also work? Also tex32f should be void* in glTexImage2D(), didn't you mean 0?

Comment: I want to extract the noise data as float, so it's only 1 channel.

Comment: Tou declared tex32f as GLuint. I would have thought the last argument of glTexImage2D should be 0, since the texture is generated by the shader.

Comment: I have to admit I'm a rookie so I don't really know what kind of code I need to add to yours, I know getTexImage2D is called somewhere...

Comment: @jokoon Render the image after `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo)`. After the rendering by the shader the image is stored in the texture object, because the texture is attached to the color plane of `fbo`. So at this point the texture can be read by `glGetTexImage`. What you've to to is similar the first pass of the tutorial [LearnOpenGL - Framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers). Instead of the second pass you have to read the texture by `glGetTexImage`.

Comment: @Rabbid76, I think you should update your answer with code based on that last comment. The question is *"How can I pull back float data to the CPU?"* But your answer only explains how to do the first part, capturing shader output in a texture. It does not explain how to pull that texture back to CPU memory ;)

Comment: @Rabbid76 https://bpaste.net/show/Dh16 do you see anything in that code that feels wrong ? shaders are here https://bpaste.net/show/Xh3Z

Comment: @jokoon `glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, values);` rather than `glGetTexImage(tex32F, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, values);`

Comment: @jokoon You've to switch the viewport. `glViewport(0, 0, width, height)` when you render to the window, but `glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);` when you render to texture (framebuffer).